# How to constraint no empty strings on an NVARCHAR column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I add a `NOT NULL` constraint on my `NVARCHAR` column so it couldn't allow any empty values. but unfortunately SQL Server deals with `NULL` and empty values as two separate values!

So how do I make the server throw an exception when inserting nothing to the column?

I'm thinking using the constraint [CHECK](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_check.asp) but I didn't find any samples when used with `NVARCHAR` columns!

Comment: Because `NULL` and an empty string _do_ represent different values.

Comment: Well I'm familiar with how SQL SERVER deals with nulls and empty values! .. I'm not asking why it accepts Empty Value while it's set to NOT NULL .. I'm asking how do I proof my application on the database level from Empty Strings!

Comment: he most likely comes from oracle, since there empty string is considered null for string fields.

Comment: I understand what you're asking, just making you aware that the behaviour you seem so shocked at, enough to exclaim as if a little  perturbed by it, is actually by design - and that goes for working with computers in general, not just SQL. Of course there are exceptions to rules...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You could add a check constraint that ensures that the string isn't empty.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Foo](
    [bar] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Foo] WITH CHECK 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_Foo] CHECK  (([bar]<>N''))
```

Comment: An alternate form which would handle the trimming would be `Len(RTrim([bar])) > 0`

Comment: Finally! :D .. Thanks for the simple and efficient answer but could you post another code sample with sample data so I could understand this part "CHECK  (([bar]<>N''))" .. btw I've used CHECK a lot before but only with INT columns!

Comment: @Thomas - No need. Trailing spaces are ignored in string comparisons anyway. And by `LEN`. `SELECT CASE WHEN N''='        ' THEN 'Empty' END,LEN('    ')` Returns `Empty,0`

Comment: Ok, but neither `CHECK  (([bar]<>N''))` nor `Len(RTrim([bar])) > 0` can filter inserting tab `insert into [dbo].[Foo]([bar]) values (' ')`

Comment: @MaximYefremov, we're using SQL Server 2008 R2, and `CHECK (bar <> N'')` does prevent a single space from being in that field, at least on `UPDATE`. It does not prevent some whitespace though, like newline.

Comment: If you want to filter tabs then you can use the `Char` function to convert the tab ASCII code into the tab character: `Len(RTrim(Replace([bar], Char(9), ''))) > 0`

Comment: Could you explain in your answer what the `N` does?

Answer (score 14):

Use a check constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable( 
    SomeColumn VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL CHECK (SomeColumn <> '')
)
```

Answer (score 2):

- If the value is being assigned a string property you can add logic at the property set method.
- If you would rather enforce this at the SQL layer then tvanfosson's answer is good.
- Unfortunately using a trigger is not going to work because a trigger can not affect the record being inserted...

Comment: A trigger can check the field and raise an error; the cleaner solution is a check constraint, but a trigger could be made to work.

Comment: Technically Keith you are correct, but I consider using a trigger in the fashion you suggest is a kludge. We agree that a check constraint is the cleanest SQL answer. Frankly, my preference is to enforce a rule like this at the object property set level so that SQL is not invoked to attempt to save an invalid object. If you can avoid the round trip to the SQL server you are better off.

Comment: hmmm your comment requires some serious rethinking! :S .. could you share your point of view on my comment on le dorfier's answer ?

Comment: IKashef, There are a lot of ways to skin this cat. I know lots of devs who prefer to enforce a rule like this at the sql layer and those (like myself) who prefer to handle it at code layer. It isn't too much real work at design time to add some "IsValidToSave" logic to your object. On the other hand, at runtime not opening a connection, passing a bit stream, etc. etc. can improve real performance. If your data layer is expected to be shared between applications than enforcing this rule in both places maybe a good idea.

Comment: Enforcing the rule in both places seems the most sensible suggestion to me. The database constraint acts as a guard to ensure that if your `IsValidToSave` logic is buggy invalid data doesn't end up silently added to the database.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for a [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx). Basically, you'd want a trigger on insert such that it checks the new value, and if it's empty string, you cause the trigger to fail.

Comment: Trigger might be a solution, but I think there's a simpler solution using CHECK constraint but I don't seem to get how to use it with string types!

Answer (score 0):

How about a check constraint that the column value doesn't equal an empty string? A bit cleaner than a trigger, and it can be modeled in code using many ORMs including NHibernate, so your app layer can be told to expect it.

Failing that, when assigning the field you never want to be empty up in your application layer, try using a NullIfBlank() extension method:

```
public static string NullIfBlank(this string input)
{
   return String.IsNullOrWhitespace(input) ? null : input;
}
```

Null strings, empty strings, and strings that only contain spaces, newlines, tabspaces, etc will all come back as null. Now, this will require you to make sure you aren't doing any simple concatenations with this field that you don't also want to come back null: null + "any string" == null.

Answer (score -1):

It would be nice if MSSQL provided a clean way to configure empty strings to map to NULL, when that's the meaning in context. But the database is not the best place to be trapping this since there's no error handling without raising an error to another abstraction level where it should have been handled in the first place.

Comment: +1 It really would be nice .. but why I'm trying to trap it on the database level is to save my program some code (Instead of checking for every textbox if it's value is empty, I would just let the application work with no checks and if the db throw any exception I handle it and provide a message based on the error number .. but if the user enter valid data then the application will run just smooth without any checks =)

Comment: This would be a *terrible* idea to support "cleanly", but it can be done with triggers already. NULL is *not* `''` and trying to magically handle it as such is an idea that is just gonna burn somebody. (One of my dislikes about SQL is actually that there is not an additional NULL-like type; instead of collapsing NULL/'' I think it should have been expanded to better-represent the information. I believe Codd - or was it another early RA proponent? - initially argued for distinct NULL-like values.)

Comment: Feels more like a comment than an answer.